# async.times function does not fire the callback

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, mongoose

I'm trying to make [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) work properly. In this example, I want to create and save a number of `mongoose` objects, and get the callback when the job is done.

Even if the objects are saved in the database, the callback is not firing. Console logs are not shown as well. Can anyone help me finding out what am I missing?

```
var number_of_objects = 5;
async.times(number_of_objects, function(n, next){
    var myObject = new Object({ random_string : Math.random().toString(36).substring(7), isActive: false });
    myObject.save(n,function(err,object) {
        console.log("saved");
        console.log(n);
        next(err,object);
    });
},function(err, objects) {
    console.log(objects);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that no errors are happening? You're creating `myObject` each time, but you save the `n` object

Comment: No errors, 5 new objects with different `random_string` created, but without a callback. What should I change in my code? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that the [`save`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) function of `mongoose` takes only one argument - the callback function.

So you should modify your code to the following:

```
myObject.save(function(err,object) {
    console.log("saved");
    console.log(n);
    next(err,object);
});
```

Comment: yess.. that was the problem. The example code of `async.times` was confusing me. Thanks!

Comment: @cor I've checked the docs and they are indeed confusing for `times` function